# i can not install mongodb compass in raspbian

Tags: mongodb, raspberry-pi, raspbian, mongodb-compass

I have a problem running MongoDb Compass in raspbian.

When I run `mongodb compass.raspbian` I get the following error:

```
bash: /usr/bin/mongodb-compass: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

So anybody can help me to resolve this problem or to be able to install and use a graphical environment for MongoDB.

Comment: Did you follow the installation instruction here?https://docs.mongodb.com/compass/current/install. WHat's the out put. Also, it seems like that compass does not support ARM devices yet.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB is only available in amd64 architecture. Not available in ARM processors.

Comment: Raspbian has also a 64-bit image. MongoDB can be installed on Rasperry Pi running 64-bit.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply install Ubuntu 23 for Raspberry Pi 5, which is working perfectly. Then, you can install MongoDB or Redis without any issue. I prefer Ubuntu 23 Server instead of Desktop because I'll use it as a server.